# Docusign Api deauthorize application

Tags: authorization, docusignapi

I cannot find a list of authorized applications in docusign. I have two sandbox accounts. One with an integration and one which has authorized it. I cannot see where I can de-authorize it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the functionality I required in the classic view under "Connected Apps" which was where I thought it should live.

This is not in the new admin view

Comment: +1 Correct answer. The de-authorization capability will be added to the New DocuSign Experience admin tool, but it isn't there quite yet.

Comment: Thanks. I like the new view. Looking forward to it all being ported over